# Inadvertently removing .ssh/authorized_keys , is it a serious mistake?

Tags: ssh

I am new to set up SSH Keys on Ubuntu 16.04.
I was looking for an authorized key to remove named `anne` but I think I deleted the whole `authorized_keys` file.

```
mike@mike-thinks:~$ rm /home/mike/.ssh/
authorized_keys  id_rsa           id_rsa.pub       known_hosts
mike@mike-thinks:~$ rm /home/mike/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Is it serious mistake?
If yes how to regenerate them? Meanwhile I did that :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/.ssh$ touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
mike@mike-thinks:~/.ssh$ ls
authorized_keys  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
mike@mike-thinks:~/.ssh$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: How did the first `rm` command end up listing the contents of the directory? Is that a copying error that should be `ls /home/mike/.ssh/`?

Comment: @Barmar, that's what it looks like in Bash when you hit tab to autocomplete the path, and there's multiple choices.

Comment: Now is the best time to think about [tag:backup] and [tag:restore].

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file contains a list of public keys. It allows everyone who owns a private key matching one of those to connect to this machine and get remote access under this user account (the tilde `~` at the front of the path signifies that this file is under the current user's home directory).

#### On the server (the machine you want to connect *to*):

If you deleted this file, nobody will be able to authenticate under this user account using their private keys. Password authentication would still work, unless it was disabled.

You'd have to regenerate the file and add all the public keys to which you want to grant access using the public key authentication method again.

#### On the client (the machine you want to connect *from*, i.e. your local machine):

Here you do not need an `authorized_keys` file, because you do probably not want to authorize any keys and grant them remote access to your local computer. It should be empty or deleted.

On the client, you only need the private key files which are authorized on the server (i.e. which have their corresponding public keys in the `authorized_keys` file on the server), and optionally an appropriate `config` and `known_hosts` file.

Comment: Thanks ! Hmm, I'm really new to public keys, private ones and remote access. This is my personal machine. I think nobody had a remote access to my machine, I think not.

Comment: If you don't want anyone having access to the machine, just remove the file or leave it empty and you're good to go.

Comment: @RoVo, just created it while trying to deploy my first online application following [this tutorial from digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-1604), I hadn't yet forwarded it anywhere

Comment: Okay, then I think you misread it. You don't need the `authorized_keys` file on the local machine, but on the server.

Comment: @RoVo Oh? Are you sure because they wrote that *The first step is to create a key pair on the client machine (usually your computer)* with `ssh-keygen`

Comment: Yeah, if this is your local machine, you should leave the file empty or deleted. It only needs to be present on the server, if you want to use public key authentication. It does not need to exist (or even should not exist) on your client machine, as I assume you don't want to give anyone remote access to that one. It will get automatically created on the server if you use `ssh-copy-id` as presented in the other answer.

Comment: `ssh-keygen` creates `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, not `authorized_keys`. And that for sure.

Comment: @RoVo Okay, So I will delete `authorized_keys` again

Comment: Note that it's quite common to want to ssh *from* another computer to your desktop computer, and using keys to authenticate in that case is more secure.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you removed the whole file.
To recreate it all users have to copy their ssh-keys on the server agein. You can use

```
ssh-copy-id user@hostname.example.com
```

If you don't want to remove all keys, edit the file and remove only the lines next time.

Comment: Thanks, this is my personal machine. I'm not sure it served as a server yet

Comment: On your client  you need the private key-file and known_hosts  and on the server authorized_keys with pubkeys